# how many times go to update solana token metadata?

Tags: solana-program, metaplex, mpl-token-metadata

how many times go to update solana token metadata. I was Updated few times using createUpdateMetadataAccountV2Instruction but still my image doesn't appear.

Comment: A common mistake is to specify the image link directly as the metadata uri. If that's what you're doing then it won't work as you expect. The metadata uri should point to a json file formatted in the way @owen.sol linked to in his answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would only need to run the command once to update a token. I am assuming that you are using the [UpdateMetadataAccountV2 from Metaplex](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/instructions#update-a-metadata-account). To update the image of a token make sure that you have correctly set up the JSON file that points to the image. Once you have created this JSON file then you can update the token's URI to point to this. To do this you would only need to run the UpdateMetadataAccountV2 method once with the updated link to the JSON file.

Please note that you need to ensure that the JSON file has been uploaded and is accessible on something like Arweave or Shadow Drive ( or AWS if you are happy with using a web2 solution). It's also important to remember that you need to stick to the Metaplex token standard when creating your JSON file ( read more [here](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/token-standard)).